# I need to points a set of terminal executions in to simple reference

Tags: linux, bash

I am new to Linux/Unix environment. I am developing a simple bash script to execute some daily drivers logic. But I need to simplify my functions by its complex codes. Are there any specific way to address these issues?

as a example, In script I need to execute this function, in wrap with predefined reference

pseudo code,

```
git init . --> (reference in) refer1
```

the refer1 should, execute as same as `git init .`

Please do not add functional solutions, it is already implemented

Comment: Are you asking how to run `git init .` from a bash script?

Comment: No I need to this command in to other simpler reference terms, such a variable, that can I called from anywhere in context of bash script. [The mentioned, git init . command is an example].

Comment: You want to call `git init .` several times in a single shell script, and instead of writing it out each time, you want a simplified name like `create_repo`?

Comment: yes, you git, please read the question again, I update the question with pseudo code +1

Comment: Your question is unclear and lacks some [mre]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In such scenarios, the most recommended way is use terminal functions as it is. In this I realised you specifically focused on referencing a bash commands in simpler terms.
For theses scenarios can accommodate by linux `alias` functions.

The simpler term if `alias` is "aliases allow a string to be substituted for a word when it is used as the first word of a simple command." You can get more advance details by following command,

```
$ man alias
```

In this issue alias need 2 parameters, the referencing alias name, exact bash function.

```
$ alias reference_name='your_bash_command'
```

This is the solution for your problem.

```
$ alias refGit='git init . '
```

Comment: why does alias not recommend ?

Comment: Alias not shown the abstract functionality  of your code.When working with teams, aliases makes more development overhead(not readable, takes time to interpret). alias is okay for single development tasks, but not for community developments

Comment: Yes, I got it. This is private code, not a community work. Thanks You @melan

Answer (score 0):

You could be interested in commands such as [crontab(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/crontab.1.html) or  [`at` or `batch`](https://www.computerhope.com/unix/uat.htm), and you might use [guile](https://www.gnu.org/software/guile/guile.html) as your scripting language (it is much more expressive and powerful than `bash`  is) or [Python](https://python.org/) or [Lua](https://lua.org/) or [Ocaml](https://ocaml.org/). See [execve(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html) which is the primitive [system call](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_call) used to start all programs (including your scripts from your [crontab(5)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/crontab.5.html) file). Take care of your [`$PATH`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PATH_(variable))  settings (perhaps not the same in a `cron` or `batch` job and in your terminal). See related conventions in [environ(7)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/environ.7.html).

The table of Linux system calls is on [syscalls(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html).

Please take several days to read books such as [*Advanced Linux Programming*](https://mentorembedded.github.io/advancedlinuxprogramming/) (online or on paper).

Consider studying for inspiration the source code of most Linux utilities, they are very often [open source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_source). Perhaps my [execicar.c](http://starynkevitch.net/Basile/execicar.c) could interest you? (GPLv3+ code, commented but not otherwise documented).

You might be interested by changing your interactive [unix shell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_shell) with [chsh(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/chsh.1.html). I like [zsh](https://zsh.org/) but you might prefer [fish](http://fishshell.com/).

> I need to points a set of terminal executions in to simple reference

Have you looked into [GNU parallel](https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/) or into [icecream](http://linuxintro.org/wiki/Icecream) ? It seems to fit your needs, and it is [free software](https://www.gnu.org/philosophy/free-sw.en.html) (whose source code you can study) that you can improve and adapt to them.

> I am developing a simple bash script ...

As a matter of opinion, I don't recommend using [GNU bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/) (or [Tcl](http://tcl.tk/)) for any script larger than a few dozen of lines (because `bash` is an unstructured language and untyped language, see [these slides](https://archive.fosdem.org/2018/schedule/event/code_parsing_posix_s_hell/attachments/slides/2525/export/events/attachments/code_parsing_posix_s_hell/slides/2525/morbig.pdf)). Linux has many "better" (more expressive, more efficient) scripting languages. Learn them and use them.

Answer (score 0):

You can create functions like in other languages:

```
#!/bin/bash

refer1() {
  git init .
}

refer1
```

Functions can always be used in scripts, and work no matter how complex the command is.

Aliases must be enabled with `shopt -s expand_aliases`, must be escaped carefully, can only use parameters appended at the end, and must be defined in a separate parsing unit to work.